# IntegrityError at * UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to create a django application to keep track of a product(product stock application).whenever I try to add new product ,I cannot add more than one product in the same category. It gives **UNIQUE constraint failed** error .

I want to add multiple products in same category.

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Stock(models.Model):
    sold_quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

**Edit:**

**Views**

```
def createProduct(request):
    form = AddProductForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    contex = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'stockmgmt/add_products.html', contex)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class AddProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Error Message**
[image: Error Message]

Comment: How are you adding a new product, the query you are executing

Comment: add your view how you create new product

Comment: I have added the code of Views please have a look @rgermain

Comment: This kind of issue may raise because of some attributes that affected the DB and then you make some changes. Did you have your model in a certain state before this you posted here?

Comment: @Lemayzeur No It wasn't Changed

Comment: Go to your model admin, try adding some products just to see if you still have the issue. If yes, edit your question by adding the `AddProductForm()`

Comment: @Lemayzeur yes the Error is same  While adding from admin dashboard aswell

Comment: @Darkness I reproduced your code and it is working normally. You may have at some point set `unique = True` in the product category and forgot to run the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands.